# How to use Enum as a user menu?

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to make a user menu for a application I am making for practice, I am currently using if statements and user input to call the method.

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

while(true) {

    //Users Choice 
    System.out.println("Please Enter Choice:  ");
    String choice = kb.nextInt();

    //Calling method based on choice 
    if(choice == 1) {
        customerWithdraw();
    }
    else if(choice == 2) {
        quit();
    }
    else {
        displayMenu();
    }
}
```

I remember reading something a wile ago and can not find it now but it basically said the Enums interfaces are preferred over if statement .

I understand what Enums are essentially a set of constants and using switch you can get the values.

I can not find this article anymore or a clear way of creating a Enum interface online.

Is there a benefit to using Enums over a if statement?

Also a basic implementation of the above code as a Enum would be very appreciated I have been searching online and getting over whelmed with other uses for Enums or even a link to a page which explains how to implement a menu.

Comment: *"Enums interfaces are preferred over if statement"* whoever said this was either talking about a specific case (not a general statement) or had no idea what they were talking about.

Comment: Enum is a collection of related constants. There is nothing in your example that could use enums without abusing their purpose or breaking good programming practises. If you want to get rid of the if statements, you could convert them to a map that associates each valid input to a corresponding action.

Comment: how is this compiling= "***if(choice == 1)***" you are comparing a string object against a litteral integer.... are u aware of that?

Comment: Where am I doing that its comparing two ints?